# CMake -- C -- Multiple Source Files Ignores Header Guard

Tags: c, gcc, linker, cmake

Okay, so I've been experimenting a little with CMake and Gtk. After quite a bit of trudging through useless documentations that don't quite hit the point, I finally got it compiling properly with Gtk and such.
As usual I started my project with a single file with one callback function defined, just to test some basic functionality. However, I generally split my programs into multiple files, one function per file, and create a common header with an include guard with all the prototypes.
This is essentially standard procedure for me, and I have done it many times in the past without any problems.
However, somehow my CMake process is doing something (well, many things) I don't understand, and I'm getting the following error:

> CMakeFiles/gte.dir/src/main.c.o: In function `gte_handler_about':
>   main.c:(.text+0xb0): multiple definition of`gte_handler_about'
>   CMakeFiles/gte.dir/src/gte_handler_about.c.o:gte_handler_about.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The main.c file is fairly simple, just loads a glade ui file with gtk_builder and presents it:

```
#  include "gtk/gtk.h"
#  include "gtksourceview/gtksourceview.h"
#  include "gte.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget   *wGTEMain;
    GtkBuilder  *bGTEMain;
    GError      *eGTE;

    gtk_init( &argc, &argv );

    bGTEMain = gtk_builder_new();   

    gtk_builder_add_from_file( bGTEMain, "gte.glade", &eGTE );
    wGTEMain = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object ( bGTEMain, "GTEMain" ));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals ( bGTEMain, NULL ); 

    g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( bGTEMain));

    gtk_widget_show( wGTEMain );

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I've included gtksourceview.h as I was starting to play with that widget in my interface.

The glade file is pretty standard, and contains only two signals, one for gtk_main_quit which is automatic, and one for gte_handler_about. I'll include that last.

I've created gte.h in the usual way, with some unique header guards as follows:

```
#ifndef PSKT_INCLUDE_GTE_H__
#  define PSKT_INCLUDE_GTE_H__ 1

G_MODULE_EXPORT void gte_handler_about( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data );

#endif /* PSKT_INCLUDE_GTE_H__ */
```

And I've used G_MODULE_EXPORT as I've read they're necessary on win32 platforms. I don't usually specify an explicit value for the macro, but I've done so in testing to see if that made a difference. (It didn't).
Originally I had the gtk headers in this file as well, but I thought better of it and moved them back to the source files.

Then, of course, I have my single function, the about callback, which simply loads a gtk about box from the glade ui file:

```
#include "gtk/gtk.h"
#include "gte.h"

G_MODULE_EXPORT void gte_handler_about( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data )
{
    GtkWidget   *wGTEAbout;
    GtkBuilder  *bGTEAbout;

    bGTEAbout = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file( bGTEAbout, "gte.glade", NULL );

    wGTEAbout = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( bGTEAbout, "GTEAbout" ) );

    gtk_dialog_run( GTK_DIALOG( wGTEAbout ) );

    g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( bGTEAbout ) );
    gtk_widget_destroy( wGTEAbout );
}
```

I'm not too worried at the moment about any preloading or optimization, and the function works just fine when it's in the main.c file, with the prototype above the main function.

The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(DEPS REQUIRED
    gmodule-2.0
    gtk+-3.0
    gtksourceview-3.0
)

SET(CFLAGS
    ${DEPS_CFLAGS} ${DEPS_CFLAGS_OTHER}
)
SET(LIB_PATHS
    ${DEPS_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

add_definitions(${CFLAGS})
link_directories(${LIB_PATHS})
link_libraries( gte ${DEPS_LIBRARIES} )

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES src/*.c)

ADD_EXECUTABLE( gte ${SRC_FILES} )
```

And I should note it took me *years* to get to that point. I was having trouble with the link_libraries portion. I should note that I added the file(GLOB_RECURSE ... ) only towards the end to avoid listing the files individually at the ADD_EXECUTABLE, and I'm not worried about secretly injected source files at this time.

**THEN** just now as a sanity check, I just tried the following commands, and they've failed as well, leading me to believe that I've literally just become an idiot and no longer know how to code at all whatsoever, and that this is probably not a CMAKE problem at all. (The backticks are there, proper, but they don't seem to show up when I quote the commands...

> gcc -c gte_handler_about.c `pkg-config --cflags gmodule-2.0 gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0`
>
> gcc -c main.c `pkg-config --cflags gmodule-2.0 gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0`
>
> gcc -o gte main.o gte_handler_about.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0`
>
> gte_handler_about.o: In function `gte_handler_about':
>   gte_handler_about.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of`gte_handler_about'
>   main.o:main.c:(.text+0xb0): first defined here
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

In the past I've seemingly had no problem building archives from .o files, with separate functions in each file, all including a common header, along the lines of:

```
# makefile
MYSRC= $(wildcard *.c)
MYOBJ= $(patsubst %c, %.o, $(MYSRC)

all: $(MYOBJ)
    ar -ru mya.a $(MYOBJ)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -Wall -O0 -g -c $^
```

And then with no problem compiled:

> gcc -o myut myut.c mya.a -lX11

All the sources in the .a were compiled including "mya.h" and the myut.c also included "mya.h" and "mya.h" includes "X11/Xlib.h".

I suppose my question really is, what am I doing differently here than before? Do I just need to sleep, or is there something different going on with the way I'm compiling Gtk?

Just for S&G, here is the glade file gte.glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
<!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
<!-- interface-requires gtksourceview 3.0 -->
<object class="GtkAboutDialog" id="GTEAbout">
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="border_width">5</property>
<property name="title" translatable="yes">About Geoff's Text Editor</property>
<property name="resizable">False</property>
<property name="modal">True</property>
<property name="window_position">center-always</property>
<property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
<property name="has_resize_grip">False</property>
<property name="program_name">Geoff's Text Editor</property>
<property name="version">0.0.1.0</property>
<property name="copyright" translatable="yes">Copyright (c) 2014, polarysekt, kb3c.uX</property>
<property name="website">[redacted]</property>
<property name="authors">polarysekt</property>
<property name="license_type">gpl-3-0</property>
<child internal-child="vbox">
  <object class="GtkBox" id="aboutdialog-vbox1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
    <property name="spacing">2</property>
    <child internal-child="action_area">
      <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="aboutdialog-action_area1">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="layout_style">end</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="pack_type">end</property>
        <property name="position">0</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</child>
</object>
<object class="GtkWindow" id="GTEMain">
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<property name="title" translatable="yes">GTEr</property>
<signal name="delete-event" handler="gtk_main_quit" swapped="no"/>
<child>
  <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="menubar1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">_File</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <child type="submenu">
              <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem1">
                    <property name="label">gtk-new</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem2">
                    <property name="label">gtk-open</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem3">
                    <property name="label">gtk-save</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem4">
                    <property name="label">gtk-save-as</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem" id="separatormenuitem1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="menuitem5">
                    <property name="label">gtk-media-rewind</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                    <child type="submenu">
                      <object class="GtkRecentChooserMenu" id="recentchoosermenu1">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="limit">10</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkSeparatorMenuItem" id="separatormenuitem2">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem5">
                    <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Edit</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <child type="submenu">
              <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem6">
                    <property name="label">gtk-cut</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem7">
                    <property name="label">gtk-copy</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem8">
                    <property name="label">gtk-paste</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="imagemenuitem9">
                    <property name="label">gtk-delete</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem3">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">_View</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="mcAbout">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Help</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <child type="submenu">
              <object class="GtkMenu" id="menuAbout">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="miAbout">
                    <property name="label">gtk-about</property>
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                    <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                    <signal name="activate" handler="gte_handler_about" swapped="no"/>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">0</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkToolbar" id="toolbar1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="toolbar_style">icons</property>
        <property name="icon_size">2</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolButton" id="tbbNew">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="has_tooltip">True</property>
            <property name="tooltip_markup" translatable="yes">New File</property>
            <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">New File</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">New</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <property name="stock_id">gtk-new</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolButton" id="tbbLoad">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="has_tooltip">True</property>
            <property name="tooltip_markup" translatable="yes">Open File</property>
            <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Open File</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Load</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <property name="stock_id">gtk-open</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">1</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkNotebook" id="notebook1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="show_tabs">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkSourceView" id="gtksourceview1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="has_tooltip">True</property>
                <property name="left_margin">2</property>
                <property name="right_margin">2</property>
                <property name="show_line_numbers">True</property>
                <property name="tab_width">4</property>
                <property name="auto_indent">True</property>
                <property name="show_right_margin">True</property>
                <property name="right_margin_position">73</property>
                <property name="highlight_current_line">True</property>
                <property name="indent_on_tab">False</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="tab">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">untitled1</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">True</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">2</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkStatusbar" id="statusbar1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
      </object>
      <packing>
        <property name="expand">False</property>
        <property name="fill">True</property>
        <property name="position">3</property>
      </packing>
    </child>
  </object>
</child>
</object>
</interface>
```

and the shell script I use to run cmake:

```
#! /bin/sh

mkdir -p build/
cd build/
cmake .. && make && cp ../res/gte.glade ./
cd ..
```

Grr, I know it's something simple and/or mundane, but I seriously can't put my finger on it... It seems like something like this happens every time I try to use a platform toolkit of some kind, and I always just give up and fall back on X/carbon/win32.

Comment: Can you upload to [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) (or similar) the output of `gcc -E gte_handler_about.c \`pkg-config --cflags gmodule-2.0 gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0\`` and `gcc -E main.c \`pkg-config --cflags gmodule-2.0 gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-3.0\``

Comment: https://gist.github.com/polarysekt/21b9fe67bd3fa7d6ad4e

Interesting... I see gte_handler_about expanded in both....
Don't exactly know what that implies, though, lol.

Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Are you sure that at the end of main.c, you don't have a definition for `get_handler_about`? If I'm wrong about this, then could you add the 2 original c files to the gist as well?

Comment: Alternatively, I think you're editing a different main.c than the one that cmake is using. Perhaps run `find . -name main.c` to see if there are multiple files with that name.

Comment: OMG... my main.c still contained the function, and I was editing a different file!
Somehow I started editing a main.c in the project root directory while my original main.c remained in src!
I don't think I would have figured that out from your advice, though.
After reading the output of the gcc -E as per your suggestion, i compiled main.c by itself and it worked as specified.

I'm not *as* insane as I thoughtm but close!

AND, as I typed this, you responded the EXACT situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [sharth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/sharth) pointed out, the problem was with the main.c file.

When I originally started this simple test app, I simply placed my `main.c` and my `gte.glade` files in the root folder of the project, expanding outward slowly.
Once I got the initial `GtkBuilder` object loading properly -- see below -- I started mucking around with `cmake`, as that was another reason for this little test.

I noticed immediately that `cmake` really cluttered my folder as I got it closer and closer to working, so I followed a design paradigm I'd noticed with other such projects: `lmms`, `simon`, etc... and automated a process to create a build folder, and run `cmake ..` from within that folder.

Once I got the hang of cmake a bit more, finally getting the `--cflags` and `--libs` to work properly, as previously I only used `pkg-config...` on the commandline or in makefiles.

The hardest part to get right was the `link_libraries( ... )` function, which I originally thought was `target_link_libraries(...)` and then messed around trying to figure out which parameter to specify. I initially tried `$(GTK_LIBRARIES}` but that didn't seem specific enough -- and then various placements of the `target_link_libraries(...)` function.

Once I got that working, I wanted to start expanding my little test app a little more, and I moved the source files into the `src/` directory and got to it. However, and this is not the first time I've made this mistake, I blow through various text editors... I sometimes find myself quickly using `nano` from the commandline, and `gedit` sometimes to differentiate from `kate` while I'm either porting code, or comparing different source bases side by side.

In this case, I had previously opened `main.c` in kate, but the proceeded to move the files into the `src` directory, all the while `kate` was still pointing at the original. I was moving back and forth across files, and I must have ignored the `file has been changed on disk warning` and saved my new changes to the original file. Meanwhile I cut the additional function `gte_handler_about()` from this original file, and made two new files: `gte_handler_about.c` and `gte.h` (complete with header guards), as I prefer a one function per file methodology. [Similarly when using C++ I find myself quickly hacking classes with inline functions in header files until they mature, and then moving them to separate source files... a  process with obvious faults, as exhibited here.]

In any case, I got the `CMakeLists.txt` file to support both source files and I started getting the linker error. While looking around for possible solutions I came across the `file()` function, and replaced the list of files with a wildcard variable... A shot in the dark, as it essentially did the same thing anyways...

Anyhow, as is quite often the solution, I came here to find a set of fresh eyes. When coding in teams, I have often found the guy (or gal) looking over your shoulder can supply fresh insight to bugs and errors, especially late into the night when my vision blurs and even the coffee loses effectiveness.

To be honest, I'm not so advanced as to know ALL the ins and outs of `gcc` as I only recently started messing around with the `-S` option to stop before the assembler step.

So finally, I humbled myself and came on to this site (only after exhausting my search engines for every possible combination of keywords, and posted).

[sharth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47453/sharth) was quick to reply ~5 minutes, and suggested (as per his comment) the -E parameter, which I supplied to gcc and output to a file which I then uploaded to a gist, noting, but not knowing what to make of, the redundancy in the output of `main.c`.

However, he was quite well on in pointing out that there may be a discrepancy in my posted code and what was actually being compiled, and as it turns out, that was the exact problem. Despite some small lag between my comments and his (this was a very small timeframe), the problem was resolved, and with most of my hair intact.

Looking back, it's almost laughable how frustrating the most mundane things can be, as many variables come into play.

Earlier this week when I picked glade up for a spin (I had previously been dynamically generating all my gtk widgets in code, which for menu-ing especially, is quite tedious) -- I was wracked with problems, which I soon attributed to the fact I was using a raspberry pi [I switched to that for my lowlevel coding as I enjoy the comfort of a fanless system, and for most applications I don't require a heavy-hitting machine)... however I was getting spurious runtime errors, which I later attributed to having culled a large chunk of my system in an effort to free up a little space on my 8GB flash.

In any case, it wasn't `Gtk` or `cmake`, it was plain old Operator Error. Another reason I enjoy the pi is because I don't usually jam it up with running applications, which IS the case on the particular machine I was using here.